# Dynamic Web project in Eclipse Neon not including jars from Ear APP-INF/lib

Tags: eclipse, classpath, jboss6.x, eclipse-neon

I have a set of projects I am working on in eclipse. An ear with a number of jars in APP_INF/lib and several projects for the wars under the ear. They are all Dynamic web projects. In Kepler and Mars the jars in APP-INF/lib show up as a library in the war projects.

Now I am moving to Neon. I have pulled in the ear and one of the wars and the classes in the war won't compile because the jars from APP-INF/lib are not in the classpath of the war.

Did something change? Is there a settings change I need to make?

I even created a new dynamic web project. I added it the the ear as part of creation. But it too does not contain a library from the ear.

I am running the web app on JBOSS EAP 6.4

Neon.2 Release (4.6.2) Build id: 20161208-0600

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why it wasn't automatically included, but in the build path, I needed to add the Ear library.